# Jmeter 3.0 Report Generator Dashboard is missing "Average" in the Statistics Table

Tags: jmeter

I was able to generate the HTML Dashboard following my test in `JMeter 3.0`.

However, the Statistics table appears to be missing the average response time column. **Min, Max, 90th pct, 95 pct and 99 pct response times** along with Label, #Samples, KO(?), Error%, Throughput and KB/sec columns are present, but Average is not.

The Statistics table in the documentation at [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) also shows Average as missing.
Is it actually missing?

Or Am I missing a configuration parameter somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Average metric is not included in HTML report because it's not a reliable metric.

Comment: In what way is it an unreliable metric?

Comment: An average is the most common summary statistic for a large number of samples, and would seem to be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Average metric has been added in JMeter 3.2 as per release notes:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html

See:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59953